# Ошибка при запросе в БД pymysql

Tags: python, pymysql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZKcL.png
Кто знает в чем проблема? 
сейчас моя прога просит от пользователя данные потом сравнивает это с бд если есть данная запись выводит ID ячейки. 
в бд когда были только цифры все ок работало.
Но если прописать там и буквы выходит такая ошибка. 
в бд вид такой ячеек.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzn6Z.png

Comment: Функция ожидает получить именно числовое значение. берите исходники программы и смотрите

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/9ir1EQ1.png можете подсказать, не как не пойму. где пользователь вводит я писал str() но результат не поменялся

Comment: никаких str не вижу, а искать на картинке нормальным поиском невозможно. номеров строк нет, так что 392 строку в которой изначально была ошибка так же не найти. Во первых надо давать все данные в вопросе текстом. Во вторых показывать кроме ошибки строки в которых они возникают.

Comment: хотя ... у вас в запросе значение без кавычек. а в sql строки заключаются в кавычки ... 'whete number = 'xxx'`

Comment: Да спасибо дело было в sql запросе.

Comment: cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM scaner2 WHERE number = "%s" """ % user_vvod) вот так заработало.